# draft.js - retrieve formatted text from db

Tags: reactjs, cors, text-editor, draftjs

My draft.js `<TextEditor />` populates `body` with the text e.g: `'{"blocks":[{"key":"3mont","text":"lorem ipsum","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}}'` and persists it to the db after using `convertToRaw()`.

In `Post.js`, I want to retrieve and display the formatted `text` from the db.
I've read that in order to do this, I must use `convertToRaw()` and then `convertFromRaw()` when retrieving it from the db but I'm having the same problems as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64850515/draft-js-unable-to-get-data-from-the-database-cross-origin-error) (I'm receiving the `cors` error and `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`) whenever I use `convertFromRaw()` and try to retrieve the formatted `text` from the db.

I've set up my server to support `cors` so why am I receiving the `cors` error? Is it because I am trying to parse an invalid response into `JSON`?
How can I get the formatted `text` from the db in `Post.js`?
Any help would be really appreciated!

[GitHub](https://github.com/Rahni1/mern_blog)

CreatePost.js

```
class CreatePost extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      body: EditorState.createEmpty(),
    };
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      user: { _id },
    } = isAuthenticated();
    axios({
      url: `${API}/post/new-post/${_id}`,
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        ...this.state,
        body: JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(this.state.body.getCurrentContent())),
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
      //  this.setState({ createdPost: this.state.title });
       return response
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (!this.state.title || !this.state.body) {
          this.setState({
            error: "This post must contain a title and a body.",
          });
        }
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

   // Attempt to map through blocks
   //getText = () => {
   // const {body} = this.state;
   //const arr = body.blocks.map(({ text }) => text).join(' ')
   // console.log(arr)
  //}

  render() {
    const { title, body } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <Tabs>
          <TabList>
            <Tab>Draft</Tab>
            <Tab>Preview</Tab>
          </TabList>
          <TabPanel>
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <div>
                // title input
                </div>
                <div>
                  <TextEditor
                    onChange={(value) => this.setState({ body: value })}
                    editorState={body}
                  />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">
                  Publish
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </TabPanel>

          <TabPanel>
            <div>
              <h1>{title}</h1>
                // display body text value here too 
              {this.getText()}
            </div>
          </TabPanel>
        </Tabs>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Post.js (display `body` text)

```
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const id = props.match.params.id;

  const loadSinglePost = (slug, id) => {
    read(slug, id).then((data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(data.error);
        setError(data.error);
      } else {
        setPost(data)
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const slug = props.match.params.slug;
    loadSinglePost(slug, id);
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
          ...
           // display text value below
          <p>{post.body}</p>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

TextEditor.js

```
class TextEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.plugins = [addLinkPlugin];
  }
  toggleBlockType = (blockType) => {
    this.props.onChange(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(this.props.editorState, blockType));
  };
  handleKeyCommand = (command) => {
    const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(
      this.props.editorState,
      command
    );
    if (newState) {
      this.props.onChange(newState);
      return "handled";
    }
    return "not-handled";
  };

  onUnderlineClick = () => {
    this.props.onChange(
      RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.props.editorState, "UNDERLINE")
    );
  };

  onBoldClick = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.props.editorState, "BOLD"));
  };

  onItalicClick = () => {
    this.props.onChange(
      RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.props.editorState, "ITALIC")
    );
  };

  onAddLink = () => {
    const editorState = this.props.editorState;
    const selection = editorState.getSelection();
    const link = window.prompt("Paste the link -");
    if (!link) {
      this.props.onChange(RichUtils.toggleLink(editorState, selection, null));
      return "handled";
    }
    const content = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentWithEntity = content.createEntity("LINK", "MUTABLE", {
      url: link,
    });
    const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
      editorState,
      contentWithEntity,
      "create-entity"
    );
    const entityKey = contentWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    this.props.onChange(RichUtils.toggleLink(newEditorState, selection, entityKey));
  };

  toggleBlockType = (blockType) => {
    this.props.onChange(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(this.props.editorState, blockType));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      // formatting buttons
        <div>
          <Editor
          blockStyleFn={getBlockStyle}
          editorState={this.props.editorState}
          handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          plugins={this.plugins}
          placeholder="Post Content"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `draft-js` does not have html output function because it's supposed to have no assumption on the output so people can tune their output however they want ([see this](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/319)). This means we'll have to implement it ourselves and if you're looking for just an html or markdown output to preserve in the database, then [this](https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-utils/tree/master/packages) mono repo can be of help. I've implemented an example of how to do it in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-violet-xco7p). Note that I used `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for demonstration which is not optimal. You may want to use sanitization and rich text components to display back the posts. As a matter of fact I'd suggest ditching html and going for markdown instead if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I t's now being displayed (formatted) on the other tab in CreatePost.js. I'm still struggling to get it displayed in Post.js though. When I add the `onPublish` method to the button in CreatePost.js, I get `this.props.onPublish is not a function` and when I take it out and leave the button as it was, I get the same output as before. @Jackson

Comment: @Rahni My sandbox already has `Post.js` and `onPublish`. When you click the publish button it'll just display instances of `Post.js`. I think you did not click the publish button in my sandbox?